# How can I change the scroll spy Bootstrap to make it work without hash?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollto, scrollspy

How can I change the scroll spy Bootstrap to make it work without hash?

this is standard operation:

```
<a href="#page"> Page </ a>
```

But i would like to use it like this (without hash):

```
<a href="page"> Page </ a>
```

it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on bootstrap docs:

> Navbar links must have resolvable id targets.  For example, a `<a
>   href="#home">home</a>` must correspond to something in the DOM like
>   `<div id="home"></div>.`

Comment: Tnx but not work this. I think the scrolSpy works only with the hash then href = "#section"

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to change bootstrap, why not just do this:

```
<a href="#page"></a>
<a href="page">Page</a>
```